# How to get the position of a user control?

Tags: wpf

I have an application. I want to show a ballon(UserControl) after I click a button on window. The ballon must appear under the button. How to set the position to ballon using the position on button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*button* is your button, *root* is your window and *coordinates* is the coordinates of *button* relative to *root*.

```
Point coordinates = button.TransformToAncestor(root).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Take a loot at [TransformToAncestor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.transformtoancestor.aspx), it works for any visual.

Comment: How to know coordinates of button relative to root?